# Expression parsing using FLEE and custom expression context

Tags: c#, vb.net, parsing, generics, .net-2.0

I am using [Flee](http://flee.codeplex.com/) to build a formula builder. It works great but the only problem I'm facing is that Flee doesn't understand [Generic Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) I guess.

I have a function called IIf declared in the expression context I'm using.

```
Public Function IIf(Of T)(ByVal cond As Boolean, ByVal left As T, ByVal right As T) As T
    Return If(cond, left, right)
End Function
```

Now I'm lets say I'm evaluating

```
IIF(A==B,1,5)
```

When I'm trying to compile the expression, Flee is throwing an ExpressionException stating that -

```
The function IIf(boolean, Int32, Int32) is not declared.
```

How can I work around this. I mean cannot , in sense, write all possible overloads of the function of all .net primitive types. What approach should I take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the discussions about FLEE, one poster managed to get Generics working. Check out [http://flee.codeplex.com/discussions/14611](http://flee.codeplex.com/discussions/14611#PostContent_49159). Effectively, the poster declared the containing class as a Generic.

Alternatively, there may not be a way depending on how your class is structured as per this discussion: [http://flee.codeplex.com/discussions/355342](http://flee.codeplex.com/discussions/355342#PostContent_836666) which states that the poster had to declare public overloads for primitive datatypes.

You might also be able to get away with declaring a generic method with objects and turning off `Option Strict` to allow implicit casting like so:

```
Public Function IIf(ByVal cond As Boolean, ByVal left As Object, ByVal right As Object) As Object
    Return If(cond, left, right)
End Function
```

Comment: `Option Strict` does not help. I also tried the generic wrapper class method, but somehow it not able to find the `DynamicExpressionOwner` class.

Comment: I ended up writing all concrete method overloads. The generic version did not help my scenario but none-the-less you opened my eyes.